# Implementing UIDragInteractionDelegate for a UIView / UIImageView on the iPhone doesn't work, though it does on the iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, drag-and-drop, uikit

**Observation:** 
Drag and drop works in the iPad but not in the iPhone. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

**My sloppy demo code:**

[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eme4ah7n94z0uxp/stackOverflow.zip?dl=0)

**Working iPad Demo:**

Here it is on the iPad. I can long press/drag on a custom UIImageView, UICollectionView, UITableView, and UITextView and things work as they should.

[image]

**Where the problem begins**

Busted iPhone Demo: 
Here it is on the iPhone. Note the part where the pointer goes over the dog. The dog can't be dragged. It seems that the text view, collection view and table view allows dragging, but the UIImageView does not. It never hits the drag delegate itemsForBeginning function, it just sits there.

[image]

**TL;DR / Question**
Is there a way to make UIViews draggable on the iPhone, as they are on the iPad?